# How to show the list_display feature in Inline admin in django?

Tags: django

```
 class CartItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CartItem


 class CartInlineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
       CartItemInline,
    ]


 admin.site.register(Cart, CartInlineAdmin)
```

Trying to display some extra fields in Cart Admin Model. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra fields to an inline by using a custom form like this:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import CartItem, Cart


class CartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ["field_1", "field_2", ...]  # all model fields to show

    extra_field = forms.CharField(max_length=5)  # example for an extra field


class CartItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CartItem


class CartInlineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
       CartItemInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Cart, CartInlineAdmin)
```